# PHP MySQL Error echo insert into values printing on screen

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP MYSql and faced an error while writing a marks submission program. When i run the program in chrome, the table is coming ok but neither the  values are inserting in the MySQL table nor the redirection to different webpage taking place. You will understand it more clearly in the code and screen given below

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if($connection == false)
    {
        echo("<h3>Unable MySQL</h3>");
        die();
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db("IGNOU",$connection);
    if($db == false)
    die("<h3>Unable to connect to DB</h3>");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$rcptno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rcptno']);
$subdt=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subdt']);
$amarks=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amarks']);
$Vvmarks=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Vvmarks']);
$chk_dt=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chk_dt']);
$roll_no=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['roll_no']);
$sbcode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sbcode']);
$ecode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ecode']);
$query1=mysql_query("insert into assignment values('$rcptno','$subdt','$amarks','$Vvmarks','$chk_dt',
'$roll_no','$sbcode','$ecode')");

echo "insert into assignment values('$rcptno','$subdt','$amarks','$Vvmarks','$chk_dt','$roll_no'
,'$sbcode','$ecode')";
if($query1)
{
header("location:studentmaster.php");
}
}
?>
<fieldset style="width:400px;">
<form method="post" action="">
Reciept No.: <input type="number" name="rcptno" min="1">
<br>
Submission Date.: <input type="date" name="subdt">
<br>
Assignment Marks: <input type="number" name="amarks" max = "100">
<br>
Viva Marks: <input type="number" name="Vvmarks" max="100">
<br>
Checking Date.: <input type="date" name="chk_dt">
<br>
Roll No.: <input type="text" name="roll_no">
<br>
Subject Code.:
<input type="text" name="sbcode">
<br>
Evaluator Code:
<input type="text" name="ecode">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Screen

[This is the screen in which i have not yet clicked submit button]

[image]

[Now i have Clicked Submit button but it only displays a line...no insertion...no redirection]

[image]
Kindly help in overcoming this problem....

Comment: If the query fails, you need to print the error message. Add `else { echo mysql_error(); }` after `if ($query1)`

Comment: If you are just learning MySQL, forget about the mysql functions and move forward to the mysqli or pdo statements. Better in the object oriented form

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` to disable the messages of  using `mysql` API. I have to say:  '**Good job!**' for completely ignoring a *warning*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the insert query with this

```
insert into assignment(`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`, `col6`,`col7`,`col8`) values('$rcptno','$subdt','$amarks','$Vvmarks','$chk_dt', '$roll_no','$sbcode','$ecode')
```

replace col1, col2, col3... with your mysql table columns

Comment: Thanks alot for ur help

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the output because your using this line.

```
echo "insert into assignment values('$rcptno','$subdt','$amarks','$Vvmarks','$chk_dt','$roll_no'
,'$sbcode','$ecode')";
```

Also you need to make sure that you have successfully inserted or not.
For this you should use these lines of code.

```
if ($query1) {
 header('Location: studentmaster.php');
} else {
 echo 'No redirect means query failed';
 var_dump(mysql_error($connection));
}
```

Because you're learning you can skip `mysql_*` functions and move to `mysqli, PDO`